# Search query for assets

Tags: craft3, search

I build a search component, and it works fine.
Now I would like to show all the uploaded assets from a specific page ("Downloads") in the search results that include the search key.

How can I do that with Craft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `craft.assets()` to search for assets, the same way you can use `craft.entries()` to find entries. See [Querying Assets](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/assets.html#querying-assets) for details. Asset queries allow you to use mostly the same methods that entry queries do. For example, you can also use the [`.search` method](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/assets.html#search) to search for keywords in the asset's title and searchable fields.

```
{% set searchQuery = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('q') %}

{% set foundAssets = craft.assets()
    .search(searchQuery)
    .all()
%}
```

Limiting the search to assets that are selected on a specific entry can be done using the [relatedTo](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/relations.html) method:

```
{% set downloadsPage = craft.entries().section('downloads').one() %}
{% set foundAssets = craft.assets()
    .search(searchQuery)
    .relatedTo(downloadsPage)
    .all()
%}
```

See the documentation linked above for more information (for example, how to limit the relation to a specific field and direction).